# Optimal way to represent multiple versions of the same data

Tags: c#, data-representation

I want to represent a room (a room map: 2d array of strings, number of rows, nr. of columns) in my code. I need to access four rotations of it (90, 180, 270, 0 Degrees). All fields: map, rows columns change when rotating a room. 
I was thinking about declaring four interfaces `IRoom90`, `IRoom180`... and Implementing them all but then I have to write `((IRoom90) myRoom).columns`  and this seems not elegant.

What is the proper way of implementing such functionality?

EDIT: I was thinking of someting that would give me an access like `myRoom.rot(90).columns`.

Answer (score 0):

One copy of the data and one public method to perform the rotations. Redundant data would be a bad idea. You only need one set of calculations that operate based on the rotation amount. You could write 4 public methods for the 4 rotations you described or just one public method that takes a parameter.

You could also create an enumerated data type for the 4 rotations and require an instance of that to be passed to the rotation method. This would eliminate argument validation in the method.

Comment: Please see the edit to op. Anyways I don't get your second paragraph. Could you rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I come up with this:

```
public class Room
    {
        public class OrientedRoom{
            Direction dir;
            Room disoriented;
            OrientedRoom(Direction dir, Room disoriented){
                this.dir = dir;
                this.disoriented = disoriented;
            }
            public int Cols{
                get{
                    if(dir==Direction.North || dir == Direction.South)
                        return disoriented.cols;
                    else
                        return disoriented.rows;
                }
            }
            public int Rows{
                get{
                    if(dir==Direction.North || dir == Direction.South)
                        return disoriented.rows;
                    else
                        return disoriented.rows;
                }
            }
            public string this[int i, int j]{
                get{
                    switch(dir){
                    case Direction.West: return disoriented.map[Cols-j-1, i];break;
                    case Direction.South:return disoriented.map[Rows-i-1, Cols-j-1];break;
                    case Direction.East: return disoriented.map[j,Rows-i-1]; break;
                    case Direction.North:return disoriented.map[i, j];break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public readonly int cols;
        public readonly int rows;
        private string[,] map;
        public int score;
        public string name;

        public enum Direction{North, South, East, West};
        public OrientedRoom rot(Direction dir){
            return new OrientedRoom (dir, this);
        }
```

I will be happy to hear any suggestions how to improve it.